# Special permutation in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

How i can generate permutations in scheme in this way: first element of the permutation just between 1-2,the second 1-4 and the third 1-3...and also the numbers can appears more than once in the permutation

Comment: The question is not clear. Maybe you should update it, showing sample inputs and expected outputs for the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd generate all the permutations for a sequence of numbers in a given range:

```
(define (cartesian-product . lsts)
  (foldr (lambda (lst acc)
           (for*/list ((x (in-list lst))
                       (y (in-list acc)))
             (cons x y)))
         '(())
         lsts))

(cartesian-product (range 1 3) (range 1 5) (range 1 4))

=> '((1 1 1) (1 1 2) (1 1 3) (1 2 1) (1 2 2) (1 2 3) (1 3 1) (1 3 2)
     (1 3 3) (1 4 1) (1 4 2) (1 4 3) (2 1 1) (2 1 2) (2 1 3) (2 2 1)
     (2 2 2) (2 2 3) (2 3 1) (2 3 2) (2 3 3) (2 4 1) (2 4 2) (2 4 3))
```

Comment: i made a solution with append-map,but your's seems better.thanks!

Comment: @VoloacaOctavian You're welcome! please consider [accepting(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) both of the questions you've posted in the site, just click on the check mark to its left - that's the way to say "thank you" on Stack Overflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Permutations using `for/list`, covered [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=graph#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._for/list%29%29) in the Racket Documentation.

```
(for/list ([i '(1 2)]
             #:when i
             [j '(1 2 3 4)]
             #:when j
             [k '(1 2 3)])
    (list i j k))
```